Davinci Configurator does not show ECU Components in the Runtime System
I have created a project with Davinci Configurator for RTE and BSW configuration and code generation also for the ASW I have configured a project using Davinci Developer and specified the reference to the Davinci Developer project in the Davinci Configurator's project setting as follow:

It perfectly detects any save on the Davinci Developer side and pops up window to reload the configurations.
Also I have craeted three software components (Atomic SWC) inside the Davinci Developer to make sure that I have ASWs available for the Davinci Configurator but in the Davinci Configurator I could not see the ECU Components tab which allows me to edit software compnent within the Dav. Configurator itslef without the need to switch to Davinci Developer:

I have tried changing the types of software component to composition type but nothing changed, also I suspected that the problem might because that I have not configured a Basic module correctly in the Davinci Configurator but after hours of manipulation configuration values I did not find anything useful.
Edit:
Here is a view of one of the Vector's example where you can clearly see  ECU Software Compnoents, Module Internal Behavior and more menu items under the Runtime System drop down menu:

but In my workspace even though I have instanced all the SWCs and also their runnables mapped to Tasks successfully I can not see the ECU software Compnoents and other menu items so here is the picutre of my workspace hope to get you a better view:


AFAIK, you have to add the ARXML files in to the "input files dialog" to import and use them in Davinci Configurator.
For BSW Plugins (e.g. your own driver / service component below RTE), you have to add the directories of them to the configuration / project-settings.

for "Input Files Dialog", Do you mean  "Project > Input Files" ? because I found that "input file" is where I only can add the project DBC files. please give me a hint if I am wrong. for BSW plugins I am totally OK with them they are already added and recognized by the Configurator.

The Project->Input Files we use to setup all the files like: DBC/ARXML files for system desccription/extract import, CDD / ARXML files for diagnostic description import, other ARXML files like Appl-SWC definitions etc.

Unfortunately, I could not completely understand your questions.
Runtime environment (RTE) will contain the Application SwC, only when the application SwC is instanced (Type and prototype) and allocated to a core & partition.

I have edited the question and add a new section at the end of my question please take a look, hope that gives you a better view.
